# Is there any way to solve this second order Riccati equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-dynamics

I encountered this problem while studying the value of a firm which faces uncertainty over the price of its output good. Consider the following nonlinear ODE for $f(x)$ where all Greek letters are constants and $f_x$ denotes the first derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$:

$$\alpha x^2 f_{xx} + \beta x f_{x} + \gamma f + f^2 + \theta + x^{\eta} = 0$$

If the terms $f^2$ and $\theta$ were absent, this equation would reduce to a Cauchy-Euler equation with the following general solution:

$$f(x) = A_1 x^{\phi_1} + A_2 x^{\phi_2} + \frac{x^{\eta}}{\alpha \eta^2 +\left(\beta - \alpha \right) \eta + \gamma}$$

Where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are constants of integration and $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the roots of the following quadratic:

$$\alpha \phi^2 + \left(\beta - \alpha \right) \phi + \gamma = 0$$

However, with the terms $f^2$ and $\theta$ included it becomes a second order nonhomogeneous Riccati equation, which I cannot solve. Does anyone know a method of solving this type of differential equation? Has anyone encountered a similar equation before?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The function $f$ which variables does it depend on? what's mean here $f_{xx}$? For the moment I understand the your problem is $ax^{2}\ddot{f}(x)+bx\dot{f}(x)+cf(x)+f^{2}(x)+d+x^{n}=0$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Is it correct? Re-write your problem. The notation $f_{xx}$ is not suitable for this problem.

Comment: @user1027216: This sort of notation seems pretty standard in US collegiate math courses.  In fact, using $\dot{f}(x)$ seems somewhat weird, because $x$ almost certainly refers to a spatial coordinate, and dots are reserved for time derivatives.

Comment: @JacobManaker Thank your for the remark, I'm agree with you. By other hand, I understand $f_{xx}=\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}$, is it correct or here $f_{xx}=\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}$? In the first case we have a multivariable function and the second case we have one-variable function.

Comment: Yes, that needs to be specified.

Comment: I have altered the question slightly to make it clear that $f(x)$ is only a function of $x$ and its first derivative with respect to $x$ is $f_x$. I believe the notation $f_{xx}$ is permissible for both multivariable equations and single variable equations; in this case $f_{xx} = \frac{d^2 f}{d x^2}$ because  $f(x)$ only depends on $x$.